# Symfony 2.8 Logout Not Working

Tags: php, symfony, logout, symfony-2.8

I'm new to symfony and using symfony 2.8. I have developed a login application, It is logging in successfully but when I logout its showing this error

```
InvalidConfigurationException in SecurityExtension.php line 433: 
No authentication listener registered for firewall "secured_area".
```

I followed this [Link](http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/security.html#logging-out) for logout implementation.

**Security.yml**

```
security:

encoders:
    AppBundle\Entity\User: bcrypt
# https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#b-configuring-how-users-are-loaded
providers:
    our_db_provider:
        entity:
            class: AppBundle:User
            property: email

firewalls:
    # disables authentication for assets and the profiler, adapt it according to your needs
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

    main:
        anonymous: ~
        form_login:
            login_path: login
            check_path: login
        pattern:    ^/
        http_basic: ~
        provider: our_db_provider
        # activate different ways to authenticate

        # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#a-configuring-how-your-users-will-authenticate
        #http_basic: ~

        # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/form_login_setup.html
        #form_login: ~
    secured_area:
        logout:
            path: /logout
            target: /
```

**routing.yml**

```
app:
resource: '@AppBundle/Controller/'
type: annotation
logout:
    path: /logout
```

[image]

why it is showing this error when i hit /logout in the browser, Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: It is because you implemented authentication for `main` firewall, and logout for `secured_area`. Firewalls in symfony are as separate instances. Move logout part to `main` firewall, and it should work well.

Comment: Great Thanks alot...

Comment: You are welcome

Comment: @gintko you must answer questions in answers, not in comments. ;)